# Alternative way to pass 'x-api-key' to AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've setup an API gateway using an API key. Everything works fine and I can call the API using Postman and passing the API key in the 'x-api-key' header. [use-postman-to-call-api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html)

For use in a specific tool, were I can't set headers, I was wondering if there are alternatives for the 'x-api-key' header? Like adding it to the url or as a request parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you would have to [setup a custom authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-key-source.html) to accept API keys from a source other than the header.